# Play Framework 2.4 @routes.WebJarAssets.at Compilation Error in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, intellij-14, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to use WebJars with Play Framework 2.4.0, in Intellij IDEA 14.1.3.

I have SBT 1.7.0 plugin and Scala 1.5.2 plugin (with project Scala version 2.11.6).

My application works well when I run it from the terminal (*$ activator run* or *$ sbt run*) but I have compilation error and no auto-completion in IntelliJ IDEA on my templates (cf. below), on the #at() method of @routes.WebJarAssets.at(..) (and not on the @routes.Assets.at) :

[image]

There is my route conf file :

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET    /assets/*file     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# WebJars integration into Play Framework : http://www.webjars.org/documentation
GET    /webjars/*file    controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

For information, I tried to reimport project from SBT built-in builder after deleting my .idea folder but that did not work.

Any solution ?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @biesior It is _"Cannot resolve symbol at"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see IDEA 14.1.3 Scala/Play plug-in doesn't support the InjectedRoutesGenerator that is the default routesGenerator starting with Play 2.4.

webjars-play's 2.4.0-1 WebJarAssets controller implements this injection mechanism.

See a similar [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8812) at JetBrains that probably has the same cause.

You could use the regular Assets controller instead until the bug is fixed. WebJars are automatically extracted into a lib folder relative to your public assets for convenience (see [play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets) for webjar assets)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css")">
```

Eventually another workaround would be to fall back to static router by deactivating InjectedRoutesGenerator in `build.sbt` (untested).
This would however require quite some refactoring of your application to implement static methods in controllers again.

Comment: I've used Dependency Injection and it works. I could have done it because I'm at the beginning of the project. Thank you for your answer :-)